# Automatically deploying docker-compose on DigitalOcean via Github

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions, digital-ocean

I am a newbie when it comes to docker.
I have a web app that contains 4 services. I manage to create a docker-compose for it.

I would like now to publish it.
My plan is to

1. upload the whole repository with the compose file and the source codes to a private repository in github.
2. then create a droplet in digital ocean

I would like to be able to publish the code easily through github only. that it will be automatically uploaded to the server and restart the required services.
what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. There is an App platform in Digitalocean. Once you use it to deploy your docker image and whenever you update docker image via github, your site will be rebuilding (ci/cd).
I hope this can be help for you.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/app-docker-compose) App platform does not support docker compose.